# Polling MySQL database not fetching new results

Tags: python, mysql

In reference to the linked so-called duplicate question.  That question asks why data is not committed to the database after an INSERT query.
In my case, I am polling the table with a SELECT query.  New items are posted by another process (and are actually committed to the database as confirmed using Adminer).
As stated below, the first time through the loop, the Select query returns all the records expected.  On the second and all further passes, nothing is returned, even if new records are added by the other process.
If I stop and restart this loop, it again finds all the new records on the first pass, but never finds any more unless restarted again.

I have a table of records created by a legacy system.  I need to poll the table and create new records in another database on another server.
I was able to add a new field (posted_in_prodmon) with the default value of 0.
I have created a service that queries the original table and finds any records with a value of 0 in the new field.  I then create the new record in the new database (using some data from the original) and then update the new field to equal 1.  If no new records exist in the table, the process sleeps for 10 seconds, then tries again.
New records appear roughly every 20 seconds.

I am using python3.9 and mysql-connector-python==8.0.33 for my service and the server is running MySQL 8.0.23

My problem is that no matter what I try, I can't seem to find any new records after the initial records are found.  Here are the relevant bits of my code:

```
class Mysql_DB():
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger
        self.connected = False
        self.connection = None

    def is_connected(self):
        if self.connection:
            if self.connection.is_connected():
                return True
        try:
            self.logger.info(f'Not connected to mysql server... reconnecting')  
            self.connection= mysql.connector.connect(**self.dbconfig)
            return True

        except (mysql.connector.Error, IOError) as err:
            self.logger.error(f'Mysql connection failed: {err}')
            return False                


class Source(Mysql_DB):        
    def get_records(self):
        if self.is_connected():
            sql  = 'SELECT id, inspection_data '
            sql += 'FROM `1730_Vantage` '
            sql += 'WHERE part_fail = 1 '
            sql += 'AND posted_in_GFxPRoduction = 0 '
            sql += 'AND created_at > "2023-06-01" '
            sql += 'ORDER BY created_at DESC; '

        # with self.connection.cursor(buffered=True) as cursor:
        #     cursor.reset() # didn't help
        #     cursor.execute(sql)
        cursor = self.connection.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.reset() # didn't help
        cursor.execute(sql)
    return cursor


while True:
    for result in source.get_records():
        id = result[0]
        data = result[1]
        data_list = data.split("\t",3)
        
        created_at = f'{data_list[0]} {data_list[1]}'
        created_at = created_at.replace('_', '-')
        part = data_list[2]
        
        ts = int(datetime.timestamp(datetime.fromisoformat(created_at)))
        target.insert(ts, part)
        rowcount = source.update_record(id, created_at)
        if not rowcount:
            raise Exception(f'Failed to update id {id}')

    results.close()   # added after removing with block above... no change
    source.connection.close()  # this is the only thing that works... 
    sleep(10)
```

I did read that I could do this with a trigger but that seemed overly complicated.

I have tried cursor.reset().

I have tried adding LIMIT 1 (started with that).

Do I need to close the connection?  Seems wasteful.

UPDATE:  So I tried to remove the `with` block as suggested by Marcin below.  His logic made sense but did not have an effect.
The only thing that seems to work is if I close the connection every iteration.

Hoping someone can come up with a cleaner solution.

Comment: As described in the linked duplicate, generally you will need to commit or rollback the active transaction to see changes made after the transaction was started.  Another option would be to connect in autocommit mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your `get_records()` does not actually fetch the results within the method's scope and this may cause a problem because once you exit the `with` block, the cursor would be closed.

Comment: Interesting.. it does actually fetch records the first time around.  just never the second.  I always wondered if the OO approach was the problem.  Wanted to be able to reuse a bunch of code as I do things like this often to fix data.  I will build a simpler script to test... Thanks